# What is a proof of data possession that accounts for fake mirrors?

Tags: secure-storage, remote-data-checking

> Alice pays Bob $5/month to host a gigantic file for her. She wants to
>   occasionally verify that Bob is actually hosting the file. To do this,
>   she selects random blocks from the file, and challenges Bob to hash
>   those same blocks with her chosen salt. The digests should match.

This is a solved problem because Bob won't know what blocks in the file Alice will audit next. But what can be done if Bob decides to host in multiple places?

> Bob proposes to Alice that he can host the file on four more hosts,
>   for a total of $25/month. Alice agrees, and continues using her old
>   audit method. But Bob never actually hosted the files in more than one
>   place; every time Alice audited a host without the file, that host
>   asked Bob's main host for the answers, and sent them to Alice.

Comment: Alice can get a very low ping connection to one of the places and require that she receives a response faster than it would take for a light-speed signal to go back and forth between that place and the closest other relevant place. $\;$

Comment: Or she could store different copies of the data encrypted with e.g. separate keys. Since Bob knows neither the plaintext nor the keys, he can't show a hash of the ciphertext without storing all the copies.

Comment: @otus This requires sending to Bob $m$ encryptions of the same file, where $m$ is the number of mirrors.